# Dropbox Syncing Databases Corruptly

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, synchronization, dropbox

I use Dropbox for syncing my databases through my Macs(iMac & MBA). And also I've MAMP setup on both of my Macs.

It all works well except that when I create a MySQL database on my MBA for a Wordpress project of mine and then try to view the site on my iMac, I get the Wordpress installation screen even though I've successfully built the Wordpress project on my MBA before switching to my iMac.

After checking the database under my iMac, I saw that it was corrupted. The database was there but non of the tables were accessible. Then I switched back to my MBA and checked the same database there as well and it wasn't corrupted at all. It was all working fine and I was able to use the Wordpress project.

Therefore I built a test Wordpress project under my MBA again to check the database syncing and the exact same problem above happened again.

But the interesting thing is that when I start building a project on my iMac and then switch to my MBA, it all works fine in both machines.

It's really weird. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is line endings (or something similar). Could windows by using only /n while IOS (which is *nix based) be using /r/n ?

Another issue could be file permissions... windows is much more loose in relation to this. Do an LS with the appropriate flags and check if an execute (or some other permission) is missing.

Finally, I'd suggest you do the following:

Make one setup on windows, and one setup on mac (in 2 separate folders) containing the exact same data (etc) in the databases.

Then get a diff program (diffmerge, diff, beyond compare, etc), and compare the files to see what is different.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions soon but I think there is a misunderstanding here. I'm not using any Windows machines.

Comment: MBA? ... ah.. I automatically thought your sunching between windows and mac. What is an mba?

Comment: MacBook Air. Sorry for the confusion.